# How to hide/disable print() statements in the release/production mode in a flutter project?

Tags: flutter

There are many print statements used in the flutter project, How to disable all those statements in the release/Production mode so that they are not displayed on console.

Answer (score 3):

All kinds of logging function print in release build also. The difference between `print` and `debugPrint` is the restriction imposed by the `os` on printing limits. If you do not want any of those function to not to print in release mode, just override it.

```
void main() async {
 if (kReleaseMode) {
  debugPrint = (String? message, {int? wrapWidth}) {};
```

Answer (score 2):

use `debugPrint()`  then it will not print logs  in release/profile builds

Answer (score 1):

Next time use `debugPrint()` or `log()` to print statements on console so they are not displayed in release and profile builds.

For now, use this little trick to delete all of your print statements at once. In your IDE, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to find and replace strings used in your project. Make sure to select your project scope lib/ folder mainly and enable "Search with Regex" option.

Find: `print(.*)` (This is a regular expression to select every print statement)

Replace it with:

Hit replace all button and you're good to go.