# What are the actual differences between the print() vs debugPrint() and log() in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, logging, console

I am trying to create a util for logging.

I need to know the actual differences between `print()` vs `debugPrint()` and `log()`.

Many answers I have seen are outdated or confusing. Also, some upvoted answers are contradict.

I am trying to print error messages in red color. I am using ANSI code to achieve it.

```
debugPrint("\x1B[31m HelloDebug \x1B[0m");
```

The above one print in red color.

But when i do the same using `log()`, its not printing in red color. Its escaping the ANSI code.

One thing I found out was log() has error parameter.
If i pass something as error , it handles red color by default.

Here in the first one using `log`, red is not coming because ANSI code is ignored. But in `debugPrint` using it's working fine. In third one it takes error  red by default. But extra line is added even for empty string message.

Code:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Is it possible use `ANSI code` for making color text using log?
Because I have other ANSI code to make different color text.

I dont want use debugPrint because if I print some thing too frequently , the system ignore the logs.

After digging some time I found out that log function is implemented in c++ in the dart runtime.As the log function is external function in dart sdk.

```
external void log(
  String message, {
  DateTime? time,
  int? sequenceNumber,
  int level = 0,
  String name = '',
  Zone? zone,
  Object? error,
  StackTrace? stackTrace,
});
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/runtime/lib/developer.cc

Also I see some different answers while digging.
The below answer says `debugPrint` only available inside widget class. Is it still true?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52241553/9248098

#### EDIT:

While using `debugPrint` and when I launch app from Android studio terminal,  the ANSI color is working in android but when I run it same in iOS its escaping the characters in same Android Studio terminal.

If ANSI code support is based on terminal support, I couldn't figure out why its having issue in same terminal in iOS.

Answer (score 7):

It is well explained in this page [Debugging Flutter apps programmatically](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/code-debugging)

`debugPrint()` is similar to `print()` but with a throttles applied to prevents being dropped by Android’s kernel.

If you have linter setup on VSCode or other IDE, you will see this warning whenever you use `print` in your code. For more information, you can refer to [Avoid print calls in production code.](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_print.html)

[image]

To avoid the lint error, you can use `kDebugMode` with `print` or `debugPrint` instead.

```
if (kDebugMode) {
    print('test print');
}
// OR
debugPrint('test debugPrint');
```

---

As for `log()`, it actually allows you to include more information on the logging output. For example, you can add the `runtimeType` and the relevant object in the log that can help you in debugging the code.

```
log(
    'test log',
    name: runtimeType.toString(),
    error: myObj,
);
```

** btw I tried log with ANSI code `log("\x1B[31m HelloDebug \x1B[0m");`, it is working as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Actually `debugPrint` prints the log in release mode also. To avoid you need to override the debugPrint function like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74936653/9248098

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, debugPrint just apply a throttles but not to remove the log in release mode

Comment: That ANSI character right. In VS code , for both `debugPrint` and `log` its working fine.
But in Android Studio, for `debugPrint` its working fine. But for `log` its not working.

Comment: I guess it is not well supported in Android Studio based on some of the answers and comments from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018071/how-to-call-print-with-colorful-text-to-android-studio-console-in-flutter

Comment: Yes I checked that. In newer versions , it has support for ansi codes. But its not working for `log()` but works for print.